# Отличия между is None и == None

Tags: python, python-3.x

В чём отличие между `is None` и `== None`? Почему вторым способом нельзя пользоваться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для встроенных типов всё будет работать ожидаемо. Но для пользовательских объектов -- нет. Например:

```
class MyClass:
    def __eq__(self, my_object):
        # Просто вернем True

        return True

my_class = MyClass()

if my_class is None:
    print('my_class is None, using the is keyword')
else:
    print('my_class is not None, using the is keyword')

if my_class == None:
    print('my_class is None, using the == syntax')
else:
    print('my_class is not None, using the == syntax')
```

Вывод:

```
my_class is not None, using the is keyword
my_class is None, using the == syntax
```

[Источник](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/none.html)

Comment: Нет. В том источнике описано неверно. Оператор `is` проверяет **ссылки**, а объект `None` является синглтоном, т.е. `None` существует один на весь скоуп запуска и правильнее проверять ссылку (ссылается ли объект на один единственный `None`). По-другому оператор `is` можно описать так: `id(a) == id(b)`.

Comment: Так же и для `Ellipsis` (или `...`) объекта, кстати.

Comment: Лучше смотреть офф. документацию. [Identity comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not), [Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons), [The None Object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/none.html).