# Валидация на None не срабатывает

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать программу, которая не будет пропускать `False`, но, почему-то, проверка на `None` не срабатывает:

```py
def nothing_is_nothing(*args):
    for item in args:
        if item == 0 or item == False or len(str(item)) == 0 or item == None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

print(nothing_is_nothing(True, None))
```

Comment: Потому что работа функции всегда завершается сразу же после первого элемента в цикле

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Comment: [Отличия между is None и == None](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1184794/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-is-none-%D0%B8-none)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачку - ***функция должна возвращать False, если среди аргументов есть значение, интерпретируемое как False***, то можно написать так (2 варианта ниже).
Необходимо также отметить, что как False интерпретируются не только значения None, False, 0 и пустая строка, но и пустой список, пустое множество, пустой словарь [и т.д](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43692661/15035314).
Для определения False воспользуемся встроенным механизмом - `if not e:` возвращает True, если `e` интерпретируется как False. В этом случае досрочно выходим из цикла и функция возвращает False. Если же этого не происходит, то цикл штатно завершается после перебора всех элементов и функция возвращает True.
Во втором варианте применяем функцию `all()` к списку аргументов. Если **все** аргументы интерпретируются как True, то возвращается True, иначе False.
В ходе работы скрипта выводятся результаты работы обеих функций для сравнимости - они совпадают. Аргумент конструируется как кортеж с обязательным одним значением True для чистоты эксперимента, затем распаковывается в отдельные аргументы через оператор распаковки `*`.

```
def nothing_is_nothing(*args):
    for e in args:
        if not e:
            return False
    return True


def nothing_is_nothing_any(*args):
    return all(args)


for x in False, None, [], '', {}, set(), 0, True, 1, [2], {3: 4}, set('123'), 'aaa':
    element = (x,True)
    print(element, nothing_is_nothing(*element), sep='\t')
    print(element, nothing_is_nothing_any(*element), sep='\t')
```

```
(False, True)   False
(False, True)   False
(None, True)    False
(None, True)    False
([], True)  False
([], True)  False
('', True)  False
('', True)  False
({}, True)  False
({}, True)  False
(set(), True)   False
(set(), True)   False
(0, True)   False
(0, True)   False
(True, True)    True
(True, True)    True
(1, True)   True
(1, True)   True
([2], True) True
([2], True) True
({3: 4}, True)  True
({3: 4}, True)  True
({'2', '1', '3'}, True) True
({'2', '1', '3'}, True) True
('aaa', True)   True
('aaa', True)   True
```

Answer (score 0):

передела код, получилось вот так:

```
def nothing_is_nothing(*args):
    msg = True
    for item in args:
        if item == 0 or item == False or len(str(item)) == 0 or item == None:
            msg = False
            break
        else:
            msg = True
    return msg
```

Comment: Очень сложное у вас условие. Достаточно `item in [False, None]`.

Comment: И вообще, учитесь писать чистый код. По идее, всю эту функцию можно сократить в три раза и уместить в одной строке без особого ущерба для понимания.

Comment: Например `return any([item in [None, False] for item in *args])`. Коротко и ясно.

Comment: Если задача просто отсеять «ложные» значения, то просто `return all(args)` да и всё (только из-за странного `len(str(item))` поведение будет немного другим)

Comment: @Глеб а вы опять пишете непроверенный код в комментариях)

Comment: @andreymal, извините, в следующий раз буду проверять( А что не так?